# JNI call to dll method does not work - UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have created Java proxies with swig from a Header File.

Now i get an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` which (i think) points to a non existing method.

```
LcDll:DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: barJNI._LC_application_get()J
    at barJNI._LC_application_get(Native Method)
    at bar.LC_application_get(bar.java:31)
    at LumicamTest.main(LumicamTest.java:171)
LcDll:DLL_THREAD_DETACH
LcDll:DLL_THREAD_DETACH
LcDll:DLL_THREAD_DETACH
LcDll:DLL_THREAD_DETACH
LcDll:DLL_THREAD_DETACH
LcDll:DLL_THREAD_DETACH
LcDll:DLL_PROCESS_DETACH
```

The `LcDll` messages show me, that the `DLL` could get loaded.

I want to call the following method:

```
public final static native long _LC_application_get();
```

The methow was generated by swig as `LC_application_get();` without underscore.

I have tried both variants, with and without underscore, cause the DLL explorer shows the method with underscore.
The dll explorer shows the method as following: `_LC_application_get@0`

I suppose that the `@0` means, that the method has no parameters in it's signature.

Has someone an idea, what could be the problem?

thanks in advance

Comment: How are you running the program? Are you including the DLL files in the path on runtime?

Comment: I am quite sure that the lib is loaded. You can see the LcDll messages.
I use: System.out.println(System.setProperty("user.dir" ....) to set the current directory.
The java.library.path also points to the path of the dll.